AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial' in Pycharm
I am learning Python and need to monitor a serial port.
i am using Pycharm with the following code.
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('com6', 9600)
while True:
    s = ser.read(10000)
    print(s)

This gives the error:
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'
PS. I have installed "serial" in pycharms python interpreter
Not sure what is wrong...

do you have a file called serial.py anywhere in the same folder ?

I found the solution.
So, in PyCharm you need to install pyserial not serial, even though in code you call it as as serial!
Of course!!!

It's not just in Pycharm, it would be through any install method, including pip.   If you look on pypi.org, the unfortunately named serial package is "A framework for serializing/deserializing JSON/YAML/XML into python class instances and vice versa", where as pyserial and several other similarly named packages are available for serial port communication projects.
